# Core data. Can't fetch/sort entities based on the relationship to an inherited entity

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

[A]<<------------->[B].attribute

Can't fetch / sort objects based on the attribute by relationship if the object by the relationship is inherited from the abstract class

```
NSSortDescriptor *titleSort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"b.attribute" ascending:YES];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[titleSort]]; 


Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath b.attribute not found in entity <NSSQLEntity A id=17>'
```

So we have the "to-one" relationship to the [B] wich has some an attribute;

When i try to fetch [A] by "attribute" of [B] i have a crash.

It's is very strange and seems Core Data doesn't support dealing with keypath which use an inherited entities

Have you ever met this????

The same for a predicate - please help !!!

Ask questions, all what you want

Comment: Is the relationship not possibly `B` instead of `b` making it 'B.attribute'

Comment: sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: In your example you state [A]<<-->>[B].attribute but in your sort descriptor you use b.attribute it should in fact be B.attribute if this is not just pseudo code.

Comment: Yes it's just pseudo code. I have made it to simplify the situation. In fact under the "b.attribute" i have "mainEntity.date" keypath in my code

Comment: It's is very strange and seems Core Data doesn't support dealing with keypath which use an inherited entities

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure the problem is that B is an inherited entity.
Usually you can't do operation at the second level (on an attribute on another entity B related to entity A).

Basically you should do it in two steps:

1. Retrieve all the B objects, sorted by `attribute`
2. Get the A objects from the B objects (really easy because you have a 1-to-1 relationship) with a for-each loop